# How can i pass multiple variables from a method to NLOG.config?

Tags: c#, nlog

Currently i have two variables inside a method,

```
float processTime = processTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
var rowsTotal = resultadoSQL.Rows.Count;
```

I want to pass these two variables to NLog.config, so i can use them like this:

```
<target name="sql" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Framework\Logs\sql.txt" 
        layout="'Rows count:' (rowsTotal) 'Elapsed Time:' processTime"/>
```

Obviously the syntax is wrong in the layout, his purpose is just to show what i want to achieve. The .txt file would look like this:

> Rows count: 456 Elapsed Time: 87878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe change the target-Layout to `${message}` and do this:

`logger.Info($"'Rows count:' {rowsTotal} 'Elapsed Time:' {processTime}");`

You can also go more advanced and use NLog LogEvent Properties:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

If using NLog 4.5, then you can use structured logging:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

You can also use NLog Fluent API:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-API

Or just write the properties directly into `NLog.LogEventInfo.Properties`

Comment: Thank you! Tried the LogEvent Properties and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I think not using c# string interpolation is a better advice. So `logger.Info("'Rows count:' {rowsTotal} 'Elapsed Time:' {processTime}", rowsTotal,processTime);` more efficient when the logging is turned off

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<target name="sql" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Framework\Logs\sql.txt" 
        layout="'Rows count:'${rowsTotal} 'Elapsed Time:' ${processTime}"/>
```